# After reload page muted video work with sound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html5-video

It's my code: 
**index.slim**

```
 .background_video
   = video_tag 'background.mp4', loop: :loop, autoplay: :autoplay, muted: true, class: 'videos'
 .search.col-lg-6.search_form
   label.col-lg-12
     = form_tag(searches_path, method: 'get', class: 'search_form_tag') do
       br
       = text_field_tag :q, nil, placeholder: 'search everything here', class: 'search_field', autofocus: true
```

**_header.slim:**

```
.container
  header
    = link_to root_path, class: 'link_logo_image'
      = image_tag ("WHERE_LOGO.png"), class: 'logo_image'
```

After clicking on `= link_to root_path, class: 'link_logo_image'` reload page and start music

At first open page video play without sound. 
When I open admin page or reload home page video start with sound.
On my home page are buttons with src=#. After clicking on this buttons video start with sound too.

Comment: do u use turbolinks?

Comment: no, i do not use turbolincks

Comment: one video tag is not enough to debug, make sure to post everything related to the issue!

Comment: should it be `muted: :muted` (or something)?

Comment: muted: :muted does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's work:

```
= link_to '', root_path, class: 'items__footage', :"data-turbolinks" => false
```